# Maven dependencies to use OkHttp as Feign client

Tags: java, spring-boot, okhttp, feign

When okhttp used with feign throw below dependencies, it throws the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/ConnectionPool exception.

Dependencies Added to project:

```
<dependency> 
   <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
   <artifactId>feign-okhttp</artifactId>
   <version>${feign.version}</version> 
</dependency>
<dependency> 
   <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId> 
   <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId> 
   <version>3.14.9</version> 
</dependency>
```

Here is the code shows how the OkHttpClient is used with feign:

```
// creating an instance of OkHttpClient
ConnectionPool pool = new ConnectionPool(1, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
okhttp3.OkHttpClient client = new okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectionPool(pool)
    .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build();

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient(client);

// creating a feign builder with OkHttp
Feign.builder()
.client(okHttpClient)
.target(clazz, properties.getBaseUrl());
```

What I'm missing to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/ConnectionPool?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.